# PHP date formatting fails with MySQL DATE value

Tags: php

can anyone explain why the following code

```
function convdate($date) {
$formatdate = strtoupper(date('M', $date ));
$formatdate .= " " .date('d',$date). " ";
return $formatdate;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM livedates ORDER by date";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

while($livedates = mysql_fetch_array($res)){

   $output= convdate($livedates['date']) . "<br>";
   echo $output;
}
```

Outputs :

```
DEC 31
DEC 31
DEC 31
```

when if i just output  the date from the resultset using

```
$output= $livedates['date']. "<br>";
```

I get

```
2013-08-03
2013-08-10
2013-12-09
```

What I want to be getting is

```
AUG 03
AUG 10
DEC 09
```

Its going to be a mistake on my part , I realise that but i'm stumped !

Comment: Is the `date` column defined as timestamp or as datetime or as bigint in DB? What does `var_dump($livedates['date'])` show?

Comment: @IvanHušnjak It looks like it's a `DATE`, according to the second output.

Comment: @IvanHušnjak as DATE in mysql ...just realised I need to be doing strtotime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong is with your function

The second parameter of date has to be a timestamp so this is the function that would work

```
<?php
function convdate($date) {
$date = strtotime($date);
$formatdate = strtoupper(date('M', $date ));
$formatdate .= " " .date('d',$date). " ";
return $formatdate;
}
?>
```

Comment: lol What to do when everyone answers the right answer ! Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert `$livedates['date']` to a unix timestamp before passing it to the `date` function. `strtotime` can do it:

```
$formatdate = strtoupper(date('M', strtotime($date) ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your function to this:

```
function convdate($date) {
    $formatdate = new DateTime($date);
    return strtoupper($formatdate->format('M d'));
}
```

The [`DateTime`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class is amazingly wonderful to use, I suggest you check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Your updated code should be as follows    
function convdate($date) {
    $formatdate = strtoupper(date('M', strtotime($date) ));
    $formatdate .= " " .date('d',strtotime($date)). " ";
    return $formatdate;
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM livedates ORDER by date";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);

    while($livedates = mysql_fetch_array($res)){

       $strinoutput= convdate($livedates['date']) . "<br>";
       echo $strinoutput;
    }
```